# Identify longest period of variance in an array of integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function that will identify the longest period of variance in an array of numbers. Variance begins when the previous number is higher than the current, and ends when the next number is the same as the current; however, if variance doesn't end, then it is assumed the variance began with the last two numbers.

For example: `[10, 5, 3, 11, 8, 9, 9, 2, 10]` The longest period of variance in this array is `[5, 3, 11, 8, 9]`, or just `5` (the length). A variance ends when the following number is the same as the current, in this case, `9`.

The function I've written works on this case; however, it doesn't when the entire array has variance, such as `[10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10]`, which returns `8`, when it should be `9`.

In the case where the previous number is number is always lower, or always higher than the variance would be `2`, because it never ended. For example `[2, 4, 6, 8]` and `[8, 6, 4, 2]`.

I know the issue with the entire array variance can be solved by starting the `for` loop at 0, but then the other cases become invalid. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Without further ado, here is my code:

```js
function findVariance(numbers) {
    if ([0,1].includes(numbers.length)) return numbers.length;

    const variance = [[0]];
    let greater = numbers[1] > numbers[0];
    let lesser = numbers[1] < numbers[0];

    for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        let previous = variance.length - 1;
        let previousVarianceGroup = variance[previous];
        let previousVarianceGroupValue = previousVarianceGroup[previousVarianceGroup.length - 1];

        if (greater) {
            if (numbers[i] <  numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue]) {
                previousVarianceGroup.push(i);
                greater = false;
                lesser = true;
            } else {
                greater = numbers[i] < numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
                lesser = numbers[i] < numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
                variance.push([previousVarianceGroupValue, i]);
            }
        } else if (lesser) {
            if (numbers[i] > numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue]) {
                previousVarianceGroup.push(i);
                greater = true;
                lesser = false;
            } else {
                greater = numbers[i] > numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
                lesser = numbers[i] > numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
                variance.push([previousVarianceGroupValue, i]);
            }
        } else {
            greater = numbers[i] > numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
            lesser = numbers[i] < numbers[previousVarianceGroupValue];
            variance.push([previousVarianceGroupValue, i]);
        }
    }

    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < variance.length; i++) {
        result[i] = variance[i].length;
    }

    result.sort();

    return result[result.length - 1];
}

console.log(findVariance([10, 5, 3, 11, 8, 9, 9, 2, 10]));
console.log(findVariance([10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10]));
console.log(findVariance([2, 4, 6, 8]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got (trying to understand the question as best i could)

```
function calculateVariance(arr) {
    // trivial cases
    if (arr.length <= 1) { return arr.length; }

    // store the difference between each pair of adjacent numbers
    let diffs = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        diffs.push(arr[i] - arr[i - 1]);
    }

    let max = 0;

    // if the difference between two numbers is 0, they're the same.
    // the base max variance encountered is 1, otherwise it's 2.
    // the boolean zen here is that diffs[0] is falsy when it's 0, and truthy otherwise
    let count = diffs[0] ? 2 : 1;

    // go through the array of differences,
    // and count how many in a row are alternating above/below zero.
    for (i = 1; i < diffs.length; i++) {
        if ((diffs[i] < 0 !== diffs[i - 1] < 0) && diffs[i] && diffs[i - 1]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            max = Math.max(count, max);
            // see above
            count = diffs[i] ? 2 : 1;
        }
    }

    // account for the maximum variance happening at the end
    return Math.max(count, max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things a bit, just increase a counter as long as an element equals the next one, reset on equal:

```
 const counts = [];

 let count = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
   if(numbers[i] === numbers[i + 1]) {
     counts.push(count);
     count = 0;
   } else {
      count++;
  }
}

 counts.push(count);

return counts.sort()[counts.length - 1];
```

Comment: This works on the first test, but fails the following three tests, because the variance never ends, it never gets pushed to `counts`